# Помогите оптимизировать запрос

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, mysqli

```
SELECT DISTINCT sp.product_id,sp.model,sp.thumb,sp.views,sp.seo_url,sp.price,sp.scope,spd.name, sps.price AS price_special, sb.name AS barnads, sb.id AS brand_id   FROM shop_product_category spc 
      LEFT JOIN shop_product sp ON(spc.product_id=sp.product_id) 
      LEFT JOIN shop_product_descript spd ON(sp.product_id=spd.product_id)
      LEFT JOIN shop_product_special sps ON(sps.product_id=spd.product_id)
      LEFT JOIN shop_brands sb ON(sb.id=sp.brands)
      LEFT JOIN shop_product_option spo ON(spo.product_id=sp.product_id) WHERE spc.category_id = 1 AND spd.lang_id=1  AND  sp.price>='0' AND sp.price<='10000000'  ORDER BY sp.product_id DESC
```

Всем привет

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли данный запрос сделать быстрее
Всем спасибо!)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Реально еще шустрее сделать или нет?)

Comment: структуру табличек напишите и объясните где какая связь между таблицами (**1** к **1**, **1** к **n**, **n** к **1**, **n** к **m**). Какие параметры в запросе меняются? Сколько примерно записей в каждой таблице? "Оптимизировать" - слишком абстрактно, мы же не знаем, что у Вас в уже имеется.

Comment: Если ты не  не работаешь сразу целиком с результатом запроса, то возможно есть смысл, делать выборку частями.

Comment: 1. Уберите из запроса shop_product_option, она не используется. 2. Используйте LEFT только там где он действительно необходим (там где в одной из таблиц может не быть записей) (условия по sp в where уничтожают эффект от первого LEFT) 3. во всех join используйте product_id из одной таблицы (думаю из sp) 4. Продумайте весь запрос так, что бы distinct был не нужен, судя по запросу, вы сначала перемножаете записи из за недостаточных условий, а потом убираете повторы. Запрос будет явно быстрее если избежать размножения. 5. после этого изучайте план выполнения (`explain`)

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался спасибо кто комментил)

```
    SELECT sp.product_id,sp.model,sp.thumb,sp.views,sp.seo_url,sp.price,sp.scope,spd.name, sps.price AS price_special, sb.name AS barnads, sb.id AS brand_id FROM shop_product sp
LEFT JOIN shop_product_descript spd ON(sp.product_id=spd.product_id)
LEFT JOIN shop_product_special sps ON(sps.product_id=spd.product_id)
LEFT JOIN shop_brands sb ON(sb.id=sp.brands)
LEFT JOIN shop_product_option spo ON(spo.product_id=sp.product_id)
WHERE sp.product_id IN (1,3,6,7,8,9,10,11,12..) AND spd.lang_id=1 AND sp.price>='0' AND sp.price<='10000000' ORDER BY sp.product_id DESC
```

Получается вся проблема была в таблице связи категории с начало собрал товары с катигории потом поместил их в запрос IN ()  с 5 секунду загрузки удалось добиться в 300 мс 5000 товаров